# How to use manhattan distance for SpectralCluster in sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to use manhattan distance for `SpectralClustering()` in Sklearn. I am trying to set the `affinity` parameter to be `manhattan`, but getting the following error.

> ValueError: Unknown kernel 'manhattan'

What is the proper kernel name should I use for it? Anyone can help? Basically, I want to use `SpectralClustering` to realize `kmeans` using `manhattan` distance metric.

Here the line of code for setting `SpectralClustering()`:

```
clustering = SpectralClustering(n_clusters=10, affinity='manhattan', assign_labels="kmeans")
clustering.fit(X)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manhattan distance is not supported in `sklearn.metrics.pairwise_kernels` that is the reason for the ValueError.

[**`From Documentation:`**](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.pairwise_kernels.html#sklearn.metrics.pairwise.pairwise_kernels)

> Valid values for metric are::
>   [‘rbf’, ‘sigmoid’, ‘polynomial’, ‘poly’, ‘linear’, ‘cosine’]

`linear` and `manhattan` distance metric are different, you could understand from the example mentioned [here:](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/metrics.html#metrics)

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from sklearn.metrics import pairwise_distances
>>> from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import pairwise_kernels
>>> X = np.array([[2, 3], [3, 5], [5, 8]])
>>> Y = np.array([[1, 0], [2, 1]])
>>> pairwise_distances(X, Y, metric='manhattan')
array([[ 4.,  2.],
       [ 7.,  5.],
       [12., 10.]])
>>> pairwise_kernels(X, Y, metric='linear')
array([[ 2.,  7.],
       [ 3., 11.],
       [ 5., 18.]])
```

Manhattan distance function is available under [`sklearn.metrics.pairwise_distance`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise_distances.html#sklearn.metrics.pairwise_distances)

Now, the simpler way to use manhattan distance measure with spectral cluster would be,

```
>>> from sklearn.cluster import SpectralClustering
>>> from sklearn.metrics import pairwise_distances
>>> import numpy as np
>>> X = np.array([[1, 1], [2, 1], [1, 0],
...               [4, 7], [3, 5], [3, 6]])

>>> X_precomputed = pairwise_distances(X, metric='manhattan')
>>> clustering = SpectralClustering(n_clusters=2, affinity='precomputed', assign_labels="discretize",random_state=0)
>>> clustering.fit(X_precomputed)
>>> clustering.labels_
>>> clustering
```

Comment: This also makes much sense. As far as I am concerning now, linear kernel just provides a similarity score for data pair, which is kind of similar to manhattan distance does. But your method can clearly demonstrate how to apply manhattan distance to SpectralClustering. Thanks!

Comment: Feel free to change the accepted answer, if you feel so. Since it can help other to know how to use manhattan distance.

Comment: [manhattan](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/metrics.html) already appeared

Answer (score 3):

The [official documentation on Spectral Clustering](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.SpectralClustering.html) tells you that you can use anything supported by [`sklearn.metrics.pairwise_kernels`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.pairwise_kernels.html). Unfortunately there is no pairwise kernel for the Manhattan distance yet.

If something alike suffices, you could use the `linear` distance like this:

```
clustering = SpectralClustering(n_clusters=10, affinity='linear', assign_labels="kmeans")
```

Comment: Thanks feliks! I see... linear kernel is to compute the dot product of two vectors which shows the similarity of two vectors. This does the same thing as manhattan distance

Answer (score -1):

The element of the precomputed matrix should be similarity rather than distance. You can use Gaussian Kernel to do this transformation